# Ticket Reservation System Using PHP Implementation

Tags: php, mysql

**How to prevent a seat from being booked twice in a reservation system?**

I am making a model reservation system for air travel in PHP and MYSQL as a project. I have a small problem.
Here ticket and seat details are stored permanently only after payment.
Seat number is assigned before payment.

Suppose person 1 books seat x on a plane and pays for it.

While still person 1 is still paying for the ticket, person 2 books the same seat (seat has not yet been reserved) and completes payment first..

Now both people will have booked the same seat..

Can someone tell me how to implement a temporary booking storage that can be used to store data while booking occurs and is accessible by other users to solve this problem and the data should be deleted automatically as soon as the user's session is over to prevent fake reservations.
Please give a reply ASAP.

Comment: @you could set up a temporary table in the database. Insert the information in there. Then as soon as they actually make the reservation delete that row. Run a cron job maybe every 5 minutes to clean up that table. So you would have a timestamp field and maybe keep each temporary reservation in there for about 15 minutes or less. This way if someone leaves while it's in that temp table then it will get deleted and someone else can make the reservation after 15 minutes or whatever you choose. This way you can see if that reservation is already made in that table.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as a user selects a seat you should should record that a seat and ticket is being held, probably in a separate table along with a timestamp of when this action occured, as well as the user's id/session id.

When you get for available seats you should check your bookings table and the temporary seat/ticket table to figure our what seats are available. When a user books a ticket you can add the permanent reservation to your booking table and then remove the entry from the temporary table.

You will probably want to have a scheduled operation that deletes all temporary entries that are # of minutes old.

The fastest way to do something like this would be to have an in memory cache of temporary bookings, such as memcache, or a global object, however you will still have to deal with thread/synchronization and race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

When you design the DB there should be a flag for already booked
If it is yes no can book it again.
Just add a checking based on that db field

the guy who set the booking should be able to cancel the booking .
There should be a log too.
The userid  should be linked to that ticket anyway so that the user can update later even if anything happen in between booking.

you can use **Commit Rollback**  in db  transactions

Comment: The main problem I see with this idea is that the internet is essentially stateless, and anything which interrupts the user such as lost connection can and probably will result in a permanently locked record. Of course one might also implement a timeout/timestamp field, so a sanity check can be made when the next user who wants to access the record. Whenever the user takes another step in the process, the record(s) timeout gets reset.

Comment: also, I can envision a scenario where this locking mechanism allows a bot etc. to camp on a block of seats and deny them.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing it, I'd implement it in the database.

have a bookedtime field, and a status field.

When someone selects that registration booking, add a record to the table; this record prevents anyone else from selecting that booking. (INSERT INTO bookings(some,fields,bookedtime,status) VALUES('quack','moo',NOW(),0) )

Whenever someone indicates they're in the process of booking that slot (IE: Every time they page reload in the same session, moving through the checkout process), update the table.
(UPDATE bookings SET bookedtime = NOW() WHERE somefield = 'someidentifier';)

Every X minutes, cron the database with "DELETE FROM bookings WHERE status = 0 AND bookedtime < CURRENT_TIME - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE".

[Refer this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/concept-of-holding-a-reservation/7589)